# Android: Text view dynamically show the text in multiline depends on the text size

Tags: android, textview

My text view content should set dynamically. Depends on the text size it needs to be multi-line and get sized according to the actual content. If the text content is null then then text view should not be visible

I tried following

```
           <TextView android:id="@+id/xyz"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:textSize="21sp"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"                        
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:maxLines="10"/>
            </LinearLayout>


 tvview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xyz);
 String tvtext = d.getText();//will get the content here
if (tvtext == null && tvtext .isEmpty()) {
    tvview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

} else {
   tvview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    tvview.setText(tvtext);
}
```

Is this correct approach?. Here how can I decide how many lines the text view should display depends on the tvtext value. I just only mentioned min,max lines in the xml file. Will android environment takes care of it?

Please help how to achieve it.

Comment: minLines and maxLines limit the number of lines, otherwise it will just use how many will fit.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating this. You do not need to specify the number of lines. Specify the width that you want (often match_parent) and set the height to wrap_content.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/xyz"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>

tvview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xyz);
textView.setText("some text");
```

If at least one of your dimensions is warp_content the hide will be taken care of automatically for you.

Comment: But will textview show the text in multilines in this case?

Comment: I seens some examples where \n should add to the text inorder to show in other line. In my case the text is dynamic. How can i add '\n ' at regular interval of text..Please answer me